# sending emails with attachments via SSIS package in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, email, ssis

I have a SSIS package that sends an email to a list of people with an attachment of approximately 3.2MB.

this package I deployed to SQL server and i have a job to run my package.

when i run the job, it fails giving me the following error.

Source: Send Mail Task Send Mail Task     Description: An error occurred with the following error message: "Exceeded storage allocation. The server response was: 5.3.4 Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size".

when I change my attachment to a image of 9KB, the job works fine.

How can I increase the maximum message size? Is this limitation in my SQL server or my SMTP server?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's a limit on the receiving mail server. If you have access to it you can configure it to a higher value.